# React useSelector hook Is it better to spread object or specify only needed fields

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

If I have a huge object say (40+ fields) and I call useSelector in a component but only need 3 fields of such object is it better for performance to just call 3 fields like this:

```
const user = useSelector((state) => ({
    id: state.userReducer.id,
    name: state.userReducer.name,
    lastName: state.userReducer.lastName
  }));
```

In this  case its okayish because we only need 3 fields, but if we need 10+ fields things can get quite verbose. In which case a **spread operator** saves me a lot of code but is it a bad practice? due to obfuscation of code, performance or some other reasons?

```
const user = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state.userReducer }));
```

Comment: I'm in the "take only what you need" camp. Apart from limiting scope, it has the added benefit of telling you exactly which keys are available rather than having to dive down into the reducer.

Comment: Any state changes in your ```userReducer``` will cause a re-render in your component if you chose to select it all. So it's very important to only select the necessary state for your component

Answer (score 7):

You should be doing it like that for performance reasons:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.userReducer);
```

Your selector will be run whenever an action is dispatched. If it returns something different then on the last run it will force the component to re-render. By spreading into a new object it will **always** return a new object. Therefore your component will re-render **on every action that gets dispatched**.

From the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector):

> `useSelector()` will also subscribe to the Redux store, and run your
> selector whenever an action is dispatched.
>
> [...]
>
> - When an action is dispatched, `useSelector()` will do a reference
>   comparison of the previous selector result value and the current
>   result value. **If they are different, the component will be forced to
>   re-render**.
> - [...]
> - `useSelector()` uses strict `===` reference equality checks by default, not shallow equality

Also I find the key `userReducer` to be a little awkward. It is just the `user` not the reducer of the user. A reducer is a pure function that turns actions into changes not an object of data.

**EDIT**:

As noted by @Adam in the comment if you want to further reduce the amount of re-renders you can use a memorized selector to select only the state you are interested in. A good library to create such a selector is [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect).

```
// example

import { createSelector } from 'reselect'; 

const basicUserDataSelector = createSelector(
    ({user}) => user.id,
    ({user}) => user.name,
    ({user}) => user.lastName,
    (id, name, lastName) => ({id, name, lastName})
);

// usage

const user = useSelector(basicUserDataSelector);
```

In your case the easiest way to only select the state needed ist to tell `useSelector` to do a *shallow equal* comparison instead of a *reference equality* comparison. `useSelector` accepts a comparator function as the second argument:

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const user = useSelector(
    ({user}) => ({
        id: user.id
        name: user.name
        lastName: user.lastName
    }),
    shallowEqual
);
```

It is best practice to only take as few data as needed to render from the store to limit the amount of re-rendering. The extra cost of selecting more data then actually needed depends on the component and the frequency of changes on the selected data.

Comment: Yes! In addition, if the OP only wants certain parts of the user reducer, they should look into using [reslect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) (not a bad idea to include this in your answer!). EDIT: With that in mind, you should definitely **take only what you need**, taking additional things you don't need will cause unnecessary rerenders).

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the input. Added it to my answer.